# 429 Too Many Requests for url: https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/

Tags: rpc, program, mainnet, close

I'm getting:

> 429 Too Many Requests for url: https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/

```
solana program close --buffers
```

Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 5):

If you are hitting mainnet-beta you will get rate limited, so you need to configure your CLI or Application with an RPC endpoint... here's a list of RPC providers https://docs.metaplex.com/resources/rpc-providers

Answer (score 2):

The following RPC servers are public goods: https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints

Those RPC servers are sponsored, and open for anybody to use. As such, they have *very* strict rate limits – limits on how many requests you can send to them before they block further requests.

The idea is that you can use these servers for testing, building a proof-of-concept, personal use, or very light-duty commercial use. When your needs outstrip their capacity, you can sign up and pay for the level of RPC service you require.

I will stop short of recommending RPC providers since that would constitute an opinion, but suffice to say that you can find them by doing a search for ‘[Solana RPC service](https://www.google.com/search?q=Solana+RPC+service).’